# Сортировка данных

Tags: сортировка, mongodb, php

Нужно провести сортировку списка пользователей (таблица users) по количеству сообщений (таблица posts), а также по сумме рейтинга ( win + lose, сортируется отдельно ).
Примерная структура таблиц:

**users**:

- _id
- displayName
- E-mail
- win
- lose

**posts**

- _id
- user
- msg
- *(bool)* delete

Как можно реализовать такую сортировку ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В sql данная задача тривиальна:

```
    select u.name, count(p.msg) as cnt from UU u 
left join PP p on (p.user_id = u.id) group by u.name order by cnt desc
```

Для mongoDB все страшнее.
Есть такая утилита SlamData (http://slamdata.com/). Она позволяет транслировать sql-выражения в запросы mongoDB

Например, для вашей задачи SQL придется слегка изменить:

```
select distinct TT.cnt, TT.displayName from (select u.displayName, count(p.msg) as cnt from users u  join posts p on (p.user = u._id) group by p.user ) as TT
```

И результатом будет что-то такое:  http://pastebin.com/gFmFEXnP

Comment: Спасибо :) Долго пришлось разбираться

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо объединить таблицу users с таблицей posts, при этом использовать группировку по таблицу posts с подчетом (т.е. count(*)). И отсортировать по полю количества записей. Так бы сделал в SQL.